# Auto-enter master password in Keepass on launch

Tags: boot, password-management, keepass, autostart

I use Keepass only for unimportant sites and it's set up to autostart with Windows. Entering password every time is quite annoying.

Of course I can use something like recorded macro. But is there any more usable approach?

Comment: Since that totally defeats the purpose of using a password manager, KeePass [will never implement such a feature](https://www.keepassx.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1633).

Comment: @Vinayak, and that's why I'm never going to use KeePass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create shortcut with following command line options:

```
KeePass.exe "C:\My Documents\MyDatabase.kdb" -pw:password
```

`"C:\My Documents\MyDatabase.kdb"` - The database file location is passed as argument. Only one database file is allowed. If the path contains a space, it must be enclosed in quotes (").

`-pw:password` - Passwords can be passed using the -pw: option. In order to pass 'abc' as password, you would add the following argument to the command line: -pw:abc. Note that there must be no space between the ':' and the password. If your password contains a space, you must enclose it in quotes. For example: -pw:"my secret password".

The `-minimize` command line argument makes KeePass start up minimized.

[source](http://keepass.info/help/base/cmdline.html)

Comment: `-minimize` does not work for me under Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I first create a new entry with my Keepass password with the URL

```
cmd://"cmd.exe" /k echo Register-ScheduledTask -Action (New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute '{APPDIR}\Keepass.exe' -Argument '"{DB_NAME}" -pw-enc:{PASSWORD_ENC}' -WorkingDirectory '{DB_DIR}') -Trigger (New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogon) -TaskName 'KeePass'
```

That way when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> (which opens up the URL it pops up with the command line I need in to execute in PowerShell

[image: Keepass Entry Screen]

The Task Scheduler is used instead of `shell:startup` as there's a limit to the number of characters that may be placed in a Windows Shortcut where PowerShell does not impose any hard limit.